# Converting an object to datetime with Pandas to_datetime not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I try to convert an object to pandas datetime with the `to_datetime` option. However it is not working.

My code:

```
ship_date = pd.to_datetime(d['shipmentDate'])

print(ship_date.head())
```

Output:

```
0    2019-11-08 18:57:31+01:00
1    2019-11-08 16:30:02+01:00
2    2019-11-08 15:28:32+01:00
3    2019-11-08 11:56:32+01:00
4    2019-11-08 11:56:02+01:00
Name: shipmentDate, dtype: object
```

Even when trying to use format like so:
`ship_date = pd.to_datetime(d['shipmentDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')`

I still get an object and not a datetime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me with and without specifying the format option. Can you provide more details such as the original type of 'shipmentDate' column in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your datetime has different time zones. You can pass `utc=True` to `to_datetime`.