# Unable to convert datetime to pandas date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am converting the date column to pandas date, date column have date with time, some are invalid entry for that I am ignoring that. Date column looks like this image with some nat value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GYh9.png)

I am using below code

```
df['datePublished']=pd.to_datetime(df['datePublished'], errors="coerce")
df_1 = df[df['datePublished'] >= '2022-01-01']
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

How to convert the different dates in a column into pandas date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779463/converting-an-object-to-datetime-with-pandas-to-datetime-not-working/58779582#58779582)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between datetime and Pandas Timestamp objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825349/converting-between-datetime-and-pandas-timestamp-objects)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: `df_1=df[df['datePublished'].ge(pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01')]`?